# MySQL - #1215 - Cannot add foreign key constraint

Tags: mysql, sql, database, phpmyadmin, foreign-keys

MySQL is for me new thing. I usually work with Oracle database. I have to transform a little database from Oracle 10g to MySQL syntax to work with phpMyAdmin.

I tried everything, but I don't see any problem in my code. I have these two tables and they just won't hook up with the foreign key.

```
CREATE TABLE Supplier
(
   ID INT UNSIGNED NOT NULL AUTO_INCREMENT ,
   Company_name        VARCHAR (100) ,
   Company_address     VARCHAR (100) ,
   Bank_account        VARCHAR (100) ,
   CONSTRAINT PK_Supplier PRIMARY KEY (ID) 
) ;

CREATE TABLE Meat
(
   ID INT UNSIGNED NOT NULL AUTO_INCREMENT , 
   Initial_weight      VARCHAR (50) ,
   Actual_weight       VARCHAR (50) ,
   Date_of_delivery    DATETIME ,
   Durability          DATETIME ,
   Supplier_ID         DECIMAL(38) NOT NULL ,
   CONSTRAINT PK_Meat PRIMARY KEY (ID) ,
   FOREIGN KEY (Supplier_ID) REFERENCES Supplier(ID) 
) ;
```

MySQL query end with error code: #1215 - Cannot add foreign key constraint

Anyone see in these two tables some problem?

Comment: Provide table definition for `Dodavatel`

Comment: Sorry, my mistake. Of course there should be a `Supplier` instead `Dodavatel`. I was translating the code from Czech to English and I forgot translate the last part of the last line. Now is the code actually.. And of course still don't working..

Answer (score 1, accepted):

`Supplier_ID` column has `DECIMAL` type, while the `ID` in `Supplier` table is `INT UNSIGNED`.

Change it like this:

```
CREATE TABLE Supplier
(
   ID INT UNSIGNED NOT NULL AUTO_INCREMENT ,
   Company_name        VARCHAR (100) ,
   Company_address     VARCHAR (100) ,
   Bank_account        VARCHAR (100) ,
   CONSTRAINT PK_Supplier PRIMARY KEY (ID) 
) ;

CREATE TABLE Meat
(
   ID INT UNSIGNED NOT NULL AUTO_INCREMENT , 
   Initial_weight      VARCHAR (50) ,
   Actual_weight       VARCHAR (50) ,
   Date_of_delivery    DATETIME ,
   Durability          DATETIME ,
   Supplier_ID         INT UNSIGNED NOT NULL ,
   CONSTRAINT PK_Meat PRIMARY KEY (ID) ,
   FOREIGN KEY (Supplier_ID) REFERENCES Supplier(ID)
) ;
```